# Allow access to read.write data from firebase database user which emails end with @company.com

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I would like to know how to create rules which allow **firebase** **database** users read and write data to database with emails end `....@company.com`.
I used example from official documentation and changed it:

```
 {
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "email"{
        ".write": ""
        ".read": ""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but i do know how to write email check here within rules.

Comment: You will want to use `auth.token` for that.  The documentation shows an example here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database#authtoken

Comment: @DougStevenson yeah, tahnk you, i just found this example, you can check if you'd likehttps://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/DEPwABMsDVk